# Odoo12 : strptime can't recognize format %p (PM/AM)?

Tags: python, strptime, odoo-12

I've got this code inside a model function :

```
data_ordine = order_dict['date'].replace(" UTC","").rstrip()        
_logger.info('Simone --> DATA ORDINE : %s',data_ordine + "|")        
if data_ordine: 
 data_finale = datetime.strptime(data_ordine,"%m/%d/%Y %I:%M%p")
```

and when I try to execute it I receive this error :

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/_strptime.py", line 346, in _strptime    data_string[found.end():])ValueError: unconverted data remains: PM
```

In the log I've saved the data that I pass to the `strptime` function and I can see that it is:

```
2020-01-21 11:12:36,221 24082 INFO db_test odoo.addons.tepp_ept.models.sale_order: Simone --> DATA ORDINE : 01/12/2020 10:42PM|
```

I've tried the code on a [Python online compiler](https://rextester.com/l/python_online_compiler) and it seems to be ok  :

```
from datetime import datetime 
str_date ="01/12/2020 10:42PM" 
date = datetime.strptime(str_date,"%m/%d/%Y %I:%M%p") 
print(date)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What's your locale?

Comment: It was like you say a question related to locale. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ones that can be in the same situation,as indicated by [@Adan-Cortez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6622544/adan-cortes) it was related to locale settings (specically LC_TIME setting).
I solved it by temporarily resetting it and then assigning the operator value after the strptime:

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'en_US.utf8')
if data_ordine:
   data_finale = datetime.strptime(data_ordine,"%m/%d/%Y %I:%M%p")

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, self.env.context['lang'] + '.utf8')
```